# Как реализовать предварительную загрузку в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Надо в приложении реализовать предварительную загрузку. Так что бы 10 элементов(PlaceHolder) загружались предварительно за экраном.
Вот код фрагмента если нужно

```
    private static final String TAG = "PhotoGalleryFragment";
    private RecyclerView mPhotoRecyclerView;
    private List<GalleryItem> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ThumbnailDownloader<PhotoHolder> mThumbnailDownloader;

    public static PhotoGalleryFragment newInstance() {
        return new PhotoGalleryFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        new FetchItemsTask().execute(1);

        int maxMemory = (int) Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024;
        int cacheSize = maxMemory/8;
        IconCache IconCache = new IconCache(cacheSize);

        Handler responseHandler = new Handler();
        mThumbnailDownloader = new ThumbnailDownloader<>(responseHandler, IconCache);
        mThumbnailDownloader.setThumbnailDownloadListener(
                new ThumbnailDownloader.ThumbnailDownloadListener<PhotoHolder>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailDownloaded(PhotoHolder photoHolder, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                        photoHolder.bindDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                });
        mThumbnailDownloader.start();
        mThumbnailDownloader.getLooper();
        Log.i(TAG, "Background thread started");
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle saveInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container,
                false);
        mPhotoRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.photo_recycler_view);
        mPhotoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager
                (getActivity(), 3));
        setupAdapter();
        final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager =
                (GridLayoutManager) mPhotoRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        mPhotoRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            int totalItemCount;
            int lastVisibleItem;
            private int mPage = 2;
            private boolean loading = true;

            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = gridLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount - 1 <= lastVisibleItem) {
                        loading = false;
                    }
                }

                if ( !loading && dy>0 ) {
                    loading = true;
                    new FetchItemsTask().execute(mPage);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Add new Page: " + mPage);
                    mPage++;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mThumbnailDownloader.clearQueue();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mThumbnailDownloader.quit();
        Log.i(TAG, "Background thread destroyed");
    }

    private void setupAdapter() {
        if (isAdded()) {
            mPhotoRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(mItems));
        }
    }

    private class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mItemImageView;

        public PhotoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mItemImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image_view);
        }

        public void bindDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
            mItemImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }

    private class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoHolder> {

        private List<GalleryItem> mGalleryItems;

        public PhotoAdapter(List<GalleryItem> galleryItems) {
            mGalleryItems = galleryItems;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
            return new PhotoHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhotoHolder holder, int position) {
            GalleryItem galleryItem = mGalleryItems.get(position);
            Drawable placeholder = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.white_foreground);
            holder.bindDrawable(placeholder);
            mThumbnailDownloader.queueThumbnail(holder, galleryItem.getUrl_s());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mGalleryItems.size();
        }
    }

    private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<GalleryItem>> {

        @Override
        protected List<GalleryItem> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            return new FlickFetchr().fetchItems(getString(R.string.api_key), integers[0].toString());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<GalleryItem> items) {
            mItems.addAll(items);
            mPhotoRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Не очень ясно что именно вы хотите сделать и в чём именно у вас затруднения. Если задача в том, чтобы с сети что-то фоново скачать и отобразить в RecyclerView, то задача не решаема в принципе, т.к. интернет всегда может пропасть.

Answer (score 0):

Что понимать под словом "предварительно"? Нет очень понятен ваш вопрос.
Если вы хотите чтоб они загружались синхронно с прокруткой списка, этого не будет т.к. скорость загрузки зависит от скорости интернета и объема данных.

Вы можете загрузить данные заранее все 10 элементов где-то в другом экране и сохранить их в кэш/базу данных. Так же вы можете подумать от реализации пагинации в RecyclerView. Например использовать [библиотеку от Google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging).